# NameError: name 'img_new' is not defined, how to fix?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

Im trying to get pytesseract to work at identifying an image as single characters and not words.
Using code: This works, but only for detecting words not single characters in the image.

```
#importing modules
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

# If you don't have tesseract executable in your PATH, include the following:
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'

#converting image to text
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\image2.png')))
```

Attempting to view single characters Code:

```
#importing modules
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'

#converting image to text
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_new, lang='eng', config='--psm 10')
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\image2.png')))
```

I get error
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_new, lang='eng', config='--psm 10')
NameError: name 'img_new' is not defined

Comment: The error means that you haven't defined a variable named `img_new`

Comment: if you want to use python, you need to learn python. it is the standard python error message.

Comment: maybe you need to use a double slash like `C:\\Program Files\\`...